# PHP: How to compare months and days( "m-d" dates) with year, month and days ("y-m-d" dates)

Tags: php, date, calculation

What is the best way to compare a month and day date ("m-d") with a date with the format "y-m-d".

for example:

```
$date1 = "2022-04-20";
$date2 = "2022-05-20";

$seasonStart = "03-15";
$seasonEnd = "04-30";
```

I want to know how many days between $date1 and $date2 are between $seasonStart and $seasonEnd.

Comment: How do you know what the year is?

Comment: If you need current year then `createFromFormat` will use that by default.

Comment: That's what I am not sure about. The year is not specified. It is like spring and winter. They don't have years, rather a month and a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime objects for the comparison.

```
$date1 = new DateTime($date1);
$date2 = new DateTime($date2);
```

For the seasonal dates, there are a couple of different ways you can do it depending on how you need it to work.

1. You can use the year from the given date rather than defaulting to the current year, if you want to see if those dates are within the season for the year in which they occur.

   ```
   $year = $date1->format('Y');
   $seasonStart = new DateTime("$year-$seasonStart");
   $seasonEnd = new DateTime("$year-$seasonEnd");
   ```
2. If you only want to compare the date range to the season for the current year, then you can let the year default to the current one.

   ```
   $seasonStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d H:i', "$seasonStart 00:00");
   $seasonEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d H:i', "$seasonEnd 00:00");
   ```

Then you can use this to calculate the number of days in the given range that are included in the season.

```
if ($date1 > $seasonEnd || $date2 < $seasonStart) {
    // in this case the range does not overlap with the season at all
    $days = 0;
} else {
    $days = (max($seasonStart, $date1))->diff(min($seasonEnd, $date2))->days + 1;
}
```

Comment: I think there is a +1 missing in the last line. Because it won't count the last day, it will show 1 less. 
This is a great response btw. I somehow managed to do it before your response. I love the last line; how you count the overlapping days. I wrote a whole new 20-line function for it.

Comment: For the seasons, as I am storing the dates in the database (a Date field), I used the default year 2022. Then I compare the years of $date1 and the $seasonStart. If they are not equal, then I add the missing years to the $seasonStart and $seasonEnd and compare the dates.
I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, though.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you're going to use the year from `$date1` if it's not the same as the year of `$seasonStart` and you're also going to use the year from `$date1` if it IS the same as the year from `$seasonStart`, in which case you don't really need to do the comparison. But eliminating that isn't much of an improvement; just a little less code.

Comment: Yeah. BTW you still have to add a +1 to the last line since it shows 1 less. 
Trying with: 
$date1 = "2022-06-10"
$date2 = "2022-06-17"
$seasonStart = "06-14"
$seasonEnd = "06-22"
Must return 4 days overlap (14th, 15th, 16th, and 17th). but with your code, it returns 3.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I wasn't sure if "day zero" should be counted or not, if that makes sense. For example, if the date range ends on the same day that the season starts, I didn't know if that should be counted as one or zero days. Sort of like a `>=` vs. `>` thing if you were comparing a range of numbers. I can edit it to make it work that way instead.

Comment: Yes, It will count.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', '02-15');
  echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
  $season=$date->getTimeStamp();
  $current=time();
  if ($current>$season) {
    echo "Season has started!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Add some description, not just a code dump.